# React-native unable to run-android

Tags: android, react-native

Following this: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html ,
I've created an empty project and am trying to run it by doing:
sudo react-native run-android
This is what is produced:

```
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug...
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip

Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 

sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 

sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

(I can post the rest of the error if that would be useful). Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Retry download, should resolve the problem

Comment: Try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ

Comment: i have same problem find any soution ?

Answer (score 19):

Change the distribution url in:

`android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

from `https` to `http`.

Answer (score 4):

Using the following steps i resolved the error :

1. Open build.gradle (node-modules/react-native/ReactAndroid)
2. Change **src** path of **task downloadBoost** with 
   http://mirror.nienbo.com/boost/1.57.0/boost_1_57_0.zip

   ```
   task downloadBoost(dependsOn: createNativeDepsDirectories, type: Download) {
       // Use ZIP version as it's faster this way to selectively extract some parts of the archive
       //src 'https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/boost/boost/1.57.0/boost_1_57_0.zip'
       // change
       src 'http://mirror.nienbo.com/boost/1.57.0/boost_1_57_0.zip'
       onlyIfNewer true
       overwrite false
       dest new File(downloadsDir, 'boost_1_57_0.zip')
   }
   ```
3. Perform Gradle Sync

   **Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files**

Comment: This works. Just want to add that on React Native projects Step 3 is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Chang the distribution url in /android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties from https to http and also change the gradle version from 5.4 to 5.5